# Storing environment arguments by \immediate\write

Tags: macros, package-writing, xkeyval

As I have stated already in other questions I am writing a problem/solution `package`. There are many of them, for sure, I have made much progress, using it in 'everydays' productivity for my needs, but is not designed for other users so far. I came across some strange behaviour, which I initially thought is my fault of wrong usage.

Basically I use a parent `environment` which is on one hand responsible for formatting the problem (configurable via `xkeyval` keys), on the other hand is is the driver, that stores the solution (contained in a similar `environment`, say called 'child')  to an extern file, which is afterwards read at the position the user wants to have it.

The problem is now, that this will fail as soon as there are other commands handed over to the key values.

This is a MWE which fails during the `\immediate\write` process when the second `parent` call is done with the `ChildOutputStyle=\YetAnotherOutputStyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand{\DefaultTextStyle}[1]{%
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
}%

\newcommand{\YetAnotherOutputStyle}[1]{%
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{#1}}%
}%


\newwrite\OutputFileHandle%

\makeatletter%
\define@key{FamilyA}{ChildOutputStyle}[\DefaultTextStyle]{%
\def\KVMacroChildOutputStyle{#1}%
}%

\makeatother

\newcommand{\Child}[2][]{%
\setkeys{FamilyA}{#1}%

\KVMacroChildOutputStyle{#2}%

}% End of \newcommand{\Child} %



\newcommand{\Parent}[3][]{%
\setkeys{FamilyA}{#1}%

%  Do some stuff before with 2nd arg of command ('problem')
#2\par %%%%%
%%%%
%
% Now write solution ('child') content to filehandle
\immediate\write\OutputFileHandle{%
\string\Child[#1]{#3}%
}%
}%  End of \Parent command


\begin{document}
\presetkeys{FamilyA}{ChildOutputStyle={\DefaultOutputStyle}}{}%
\immediate\openout\OutputFileHandle=\jobname.myext


\textbf{\textcolor{violet}{First 'Parent' content}}% 
\par
\Parent{One Ring To Rule Them All}{One Ring To Find Them}  % I hope, Tolkien does not mind! 

%%% This code breaks when tried to save it immediately to another file!!!!
\Parent[ChildOutputStyle=\YetAnotherOutputStyle]{When shall we three meet again}{In Thunder, lightning or in rain} % William Shakespeare will not mind ;-)
%%%%


\immediate\closeout\OutputFileHandle

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Now 'Child' content}}% 
\par
\input{\jobname.myext} % replace it afterwards with \IncludeIfFileExists... etc.

\end{document}
```

The compilation fails with this message

```
! Use of \XKV@resa doesn't match its definition.
\XKV@for@n #1#2#3->\XKV@tempa@toks {#1}\edef #2{
                                                \the \XKV@tempa@toks }\ifx #...
l.57 ...t again}{In Thunder, lightning or in rain}
```

Is there any workaround (besides using the `verbatim`/`moreverb` packages?)

Some remarks at the end:

- I have replaced the `\newenvironment` statements from my original
  package by `\newcommand`s, to make the example shorter, but I prefer
  the environment style.
- The `\DefaultTextStyle` and `\YetAnotherOutputStyle` commands are
  just placeholders for some 'arbitrary' commands.
- I omitted `\AtBeginDocument` for opening the file and `AtEndDocument`
  for closing it also to keep the code short.

I am sure other users will profit from a solution as well.

Comment: I am not fully sure whether your problem could be solved using these: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8095/automatically-adding-potentially-referenced-macros-from-auxillary-file or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52256/automatic-deletion-of-unused-macros/52264#52264

Comment: You have to use the "immediate" version of `\protected@write`, but also to protect `\textcolor` which is fragile. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75951/how-to-write-the-symbol-into-a-file-when-using-package-utf8inputenc for `\protected@iwrite`. Add `\protect` before `\textcolor` or use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for the styles.

Comment: @zeroth: On a first glance I am not sure that topic/solution is connected to my question, but I will return to it.

Comment: @ChristianH. Ok, nevermind then... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The big problem is that you want to pass to `\write` commands such as `\textbf` or `\textcolor` that don't survive it. The kernel has `\protected@write` for this, but no “immediate” version.

However, it's easy to define one as done in [How to write the € symbol into a file, when using Package [utf8]{inputenc}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75951/how-to-write-the-symbol-into-a-file-when-using-package-utf8inputenc)

You also must ensure that `\textcolor` is protected, because it's fragile by itself; the easiest way is to define the styles with `\DeclareRobustCommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\DefaultTextStyle}[1]{%
  \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\YetAnotherOutputStyle}[1]{%
  \textbf{\textcolor{green}{#1}}%
}


\newwrite\OutputFileHandle

\makeatletter
\define@key{FamilyA}{ChildOutputStyle}[\DefaultTextStyle]{%
  \def\KVMacroChildOutputStyle{#1}%
}


\newcommand{\Child}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{FamilyA}{#1}
  \KVMacroChildOutputStyle{#2}%
}

%%% Helper macro
\long\def\protected@iwrite#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

\newcommand{\Parent}[3][]{%
  \setkeys{FamilyA}{#1}%
  %  Do some stuff before with 2nd arg of command ('problem')
  #2\par %%%%%
  %%%%
  %
  % Now write solution ('child') content to filehandle
  \protected@iwrite\OutputFileHandle{}{%
    \string\Child[#1]{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\presetkeys{FamilyA}{ChildOutputStyle={\DefaultTextStyle}}{}%
\immediate\openout\OutputFileHandle=\jobname.myext


\textbf{\textcolor{violet}{First 'Parent' content}}

\Parent{One Ring To Rule Them All}{One Ring To Find Them}  % I hope, Tolkien does not mind! 

%%% This code breaks when tried to save it immediately to another file!!!!
\Parent[ChildOutputStyle=\YetAnotherOutputStyle]{When shall we three meet again}{In Thunder, lightning or in rain} % William Shakespeare will not mind ;-)
%%%%


\immediate\closeout\OutputFileHandle

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Now 'Child' content}}

\input{\jobname.myext} % replace it afterwards with \IncludeIfFileExists... etc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the content of the `.myext` file:

```
\Child[]{One Ring To Find Them}
\Child[ChildOutputStyle=\protect \YetAnotherOutputStyle  ]{In Thunder, lightning or in rain}
```

---

A different strategy uses `\write`, but accompanying it with `\unexpanded`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand{\DefaultTextStyle}[1]{%
  \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\YetAnotherOutputStyle}[1]{%
  \textbf{\textcolor{green}{#1}}%
}


\newwrite\OutputFileHandle

\makeatletter
\define@key{FamilyA}{ChildOutputStyle}[\DefaultTextStyle]{%
  \def\KVMacroChildOutputStyle{#1}%
}


\newcommand{\Child}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{FamilyA}{#1}
  \KVMacroChildOutputStyle{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\Parent}[3][]{%
  \setkeys{FamilyA}{#1}%
  %  Do some stuff before with 2nd arg of command ('problem')
  #2\par %%%%%
  %%%%
  %
  % Now write solution ('child') content to filehandle
  \immediate\write\OutputFileHandle{%
    \string\Child[\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}]{\unexpanded{#3}}%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\presetkeys{FamilyA}{ChildOutputStyle={\DefaultTextStyle}}{}%
\immediate\openout\OutputFileHandle=\jobname.myext


\textbf{\textcolor{violet}{First 'Parent' content}}

\Parent{One Ring To Rule Them All}
       {One Ring To Find Them}  % I hope, Tolkien does not mind! 

%%% This code breaks when tried to save it immediately to another file!!!!
\Parent[ChildOutputStyle=\YetAnotherOutputStyle]
       {When shall we three meet again}
       {In Thunder, lightning or in rain} % William Shakespeare will not mind ;-)

\Parent[ChildOutputStyle=\DefaultTextStyle]
       {A formula}
       {\begin{math}\sqrt{2}^2=2\end{math}}

%%%%


\immediate\closeout\OutputFileHandle

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Now 'Child' content}}

\input{\jobname.myext} % replace it afterwards with \IncludeIfFileExists... etc.

\end{document}
```

Here's the output in the `.myext` file:

```
\Child[]{One Ring To Find Them}
\Child[ChildOutputStyle=\YetAnotherOutputStyle ]{In Thunder, lightning or in rain}
\Child[ChildOutputStyle=\DefaultTextStyle ]{\begin {math}\sqrt {2}^2=2\end {math}}
```

Comment: I tested your solution -- Unfortunately the compilation jumps out of the window precisely at the `\showtoken` statement. I am using TeXLive 2013, so it should not be an issue with an outdated version, but otherwise I see a very sophisticated solution. The `\DeclareRobustCommand` should probably applied to any 'style' or whatever command?

Comment: Sorry, I used `\showtokens` for debugging, it wasn't meant to be in the "production version".

Comment: It works now as a MWE, I want to test it in the true package tomorrow

Comment: I does not work since I use the 3rd argument of the parent environment as content for the child, which should be written to file, with any markup. If one changes the third argument of `\Parent` to `\begin{math} E = mc^2 \end{math}`, it will fail again, most probably due to the reason you stated alreay -- the complex content in an argument will break. Is there any way to robustify this argument right from the start such that the user does not have to do him/herself?

Comment: @ChristianH. I added an alternative version

Comment: I will try it in the afternoon, I have no access to my package code at the moment.

Comment: It works as desired -- I experimented before asking the question with `\expandafter` but not in combination with `unexpanded`, in a previous version I stored the options to a token and expanded it afterwards.