# Convert from LaTeX to Plain TeX

Tags: conversion, plain-tex

Is there a way to convert a LaTeX document, which uses a lot of packages and macros, into Plain TeX, such that all macros are expanded and all dependencies on external packages are gone?

Answer (score 9):

No. See also the FAQ:

https://texfaq.org/FAQ-LaTeXtoPlain

And this question: [LaTeX macro expander](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/latex-macro-expander)