# File .tex but content is LaTeX?

Tags: macros, installing, compiling

I'm reading the content of `The TexBook` then I realized the big difference between LaTeX and TeX. The fact is that LaTeX pre-programs huge things, like sections, titles, paragraphs, so the user does not have to always type it like he should do in TeX.

But I'm using TexWorks and when I see my saved .tex file it has **LaTeX** content, not only **TeX**. Why?

Comment: TeX's default extension is `.tex`, so everybody uses it for all kind of files, be they Plain TeX or LaTeX. You can choose from within TeXworks the engine for compiling the document.

Comment: @egreg is there a place where I can see the real .tex file that is generated from the LaTeX input?

Comment: @MrJant See the question [Convert from LaTeX to Plain TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21281/convert-from-latex-to-plain-tex) and the links therein.

Comment: @MrJant Sorry, but I don't understand. There is no *real* `.tex` file generated from LaTeX input.