# .tex file with catchfilebetweentags macros expanded

Tags: expansion, catchfile

I have a .tex file, say original.tex, where I have imported snippets from several other  files using the \catchfilebetweentags command. For archiving, I wish to produce a version of original.tex that already has all those snippets, so that I do not have to keep and maintain the other files. 
Is there an easy way to do so?
Unlike the related question at [LaTeX macro expander](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/latex-macro-expander), I do NOT want ALL macros expanded because that would make original.tex unreadable.

Comment: This is a job for something like Perl

Comment: Sounds like a job for version control to me.