# How to extract expanded equations that use commands?

Tags: math-mode, macros, compiling

I have a document with a lot of equations that use commands to maintain consistency. For example, it looks like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\numberOfDocuments}{\mathcal{N}}
\newcommand{\someSimpleCommand}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\someComplexCommand}[1]{\sum_{i = #1}^{#1+5} i}

\begin{document}

This is $\numberOfDocuments = 1$ document with equations
\begin{align}
\someSimpleCommand \approx \someComplexCommand{\numberOfDocuments}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

In order to use the resulting equations for example at MathOverflow or other places where I can not provide a complex document, I want to extract the plain TeX equations like

```
\mathcal{N} = 1
\mathcal{F} \approx \sum_{i = \mathcal{N}}^{\mathcal{N}+5} i
```

Is there any way to do this? Is there maybe an intermediate step in the LaTeX compilation process that I could access? It does not really matter if I get the whole document with the expanded equations or only the equations itself.

Comment: There isn't, you'll need an external tool to make the replacements. There might be available scripts, but since latex is a language thst can change it self, there are no universal script

Comment: The [de-macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144322/85881) works like a charm for the given example.