# `xparse` instructions and `enumitem` formatting appear to be lost on `pandoc`

Tags: enumitem

`xparse` instructions and `enumitem` formatting appear to be lost on `pandoc` (inline and `{{; }}` in this case).  It's been pointed out [conversion from LaTeX to TeX is not possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/latex-macro-expander), so what are the options?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlist{foo}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[foo]{label=\arabic*), itemjoin={{; }}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn\g__erw_foo_tl{\item \textbf{a}\item b} % 

\NewDocumentCommand\Foo{}{\tl_use:N\g__erw_foo_tl}
\NewDocumentCommand\Bar{}{\item \textbf{c}\item d}
\def\Qux{\item \textbf{e}\item f}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}
  \Foo\Bar\Qux
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

CLI

```
$ pandoc -f latex -t plain jobname.tex
E

f
```

[image]

Comment: This works: `make4ht LaTeX-292.tex && html2text LaTeX-292.html`

Comment: @michal.h21, it works with regard to `xparse` and `enumitem`, but `\textbf` is ignored, and character `Â` is inserted before each letter.