# write to file full expansion of command

Tags: expl3, xparse, xstring

I have an issue I want to resolve, maybe you can help me.

When I compile the mwe the following happens:

In the PDF you can see: `(X/A)(Up/Down)`

In the file.txt write: `(\frac {a}{x})(\frac {u}{d})`

How can I write to the file what is seen in the PDF?

mwe:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,xstring}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\frac}{mm}{
\IfStrEqCase{#1}{{a}{X}}[Up]
/
\IfStrEqCase{#2}{{x}{A}}[Down]
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Write}{+m}{
\iow_new:N \tdm_iow
\cs_gset:Npn \my_wrr:x ##1{
 \iow_open:Nn \tdm_iow { file.txt }
 \iow_now:Nx \tdm_iow{##1}
}
\my_wrr:x {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\str{(\frac{a}{x})(\frac{u}{d})}
\str
\Write{\str}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can't typically. The typeset version is a combination of glyphs from fonts, rules drawn by TeX and positioning commands, it does not have a text version that you can write to a text file.

Comment: The issue its from xstring or xparse?
because with

`\def\frac#1#2{#1/#2}`

write to file

`(a/x)(u/d)`

Comment: both. Neither \RenewDocumentCommand nor \IfStrEqCase are expandable.

Comment: well xstring commands are not expandable and xparse/lcmd ones aren' unless you use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`  but that isn't really relaed to "what appears in the pdf"

Comment: Here it's meant "you can't generally". [expansion - LaTeX macro expander - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/latex-macro-expander)

Comment: But... if `\Write` and `\frac` are things you define yourself, you can. (I make `execinside` package for such purpose and other purposes, although... currently undocumented and not on ctan...)

Comment: To be fair... `unravel` can probably do what you want (emulate TeX within TeX to get the characters that is going to be executed) but that's most likely overkill.

Comment: By the way if you learn expl3 you should also learn how expansion work properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of *xstring*'s non-expandable `\IfStrEqCase` use *expl3*'s expandable `\strcase:nnTF`.
Instead of `\RenewDocumentCommand` use `\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

(With an up-to-date TeX-installation you need neither `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` nor `\usepackage{expl3,xparse}`.)

```latex
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\frac}{mm}{
  \str_case:nnTF{#1}{{a}{X}}{}{Up}
  /
  \str_case:nnTF {#2}{{x}{A}}{}{Down}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Write}{+m}{
\iow_new:N \tdm_iow
\cs_gset:Npn \my_wrr:x ##1{
 \iow_open:Nn \tdm_iow { file.txt }
 \iow_now:Nx \tdm_iow{##1}
}
\my_wrr:x {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\str{(\frac{a}{x})(\frac{u}{d})}
\str
\Write{\str}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**file.txt**:

```
(X/A)(Up/Down)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would redefine `\frac`, so I'll use a different name.

1. `\iow_new:N` should be outside `\Write`
2. There is no need to set a function inside `\Write`
3. `\IfStrEq` is not fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment for older LaTeX

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\FRAC}{mm}
  {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 } { {a}{X} } { Up }
    /
    \str_case:nnF { #1 } { {x}{A} } { Down }
  }

\iow_new:N \rodriguez_out_iow

\NewDocumentCommand{\Write}{O{\c_sys_jobname_str.txt}m}
  {
    \rodriguez_write:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new:Nn \rodriguez_write:nn
  {
    \iow_open:Nn \rodriguez_out_iow { #1 }
    \iow_now:Nx \rodriguez_out_iow { #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\str{(\FRAC{a}{x})(\FRAC{u}{d})}

\str

\Write{\str}

\end{document}
```

The file `\jobname.txt` will contain

```
(X/Down)(Up/Down)
```

The PDF will be

[image]