# How to make lualatex output the preprocessed .tex file?

Tags: luatex, tex-core, output

My own Latex writing platform is very complicated with many self-defined macros and lua functions. My platform works fine to produce .pdf output. Now, a journal submission website requires uploading the .tex source file along with .pdf file. I want to know the way of making lualatex to produce the .tex output after all the macros having been substituted. In this case, I will be able to upload a single clean .tex source file without having to upload all the raw source code with macros definitions and lua function specifications. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/latex-macro-expander maybe that fits your bill, although I don't think you can get rid of the lua code

Comment: you can not, in general, expand all macros, that is not how tex works. You can of course replace simple cases.